# Converting code from Xcode to MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I am working in **MSVS2017**. The project was originally developed using **Xcode** and runs fine on my Mac. The project is contained in about 20 files.

In the file containing the main program, `#include "stdafx.h"` does not generate any error. However, in each file containing subsidiary functions, `#include "stdafx.h"` generates the error `"cannot open source file stdafx.h"`.

Within my `stdafx.h`, each `"#include..."` to one of my own header files generates the error `"cannot open source file ..."`.

What must I do to sort out these errors please?

Comment: Did you try Microsoft's [xcode import wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt735163.aspx)?

Comment: ***What must I do to sort out these errors please?*** I would open explorer and verify the existence of the files. I mean do the secondary projects have a `stdafx.h` file in the secondary project folder? If not create one...

Comment: My crystal ball says that the source code file for the "subsidiary functions" is stored in a different directory.  Project > Properties > C/C++ > General, Additional Include Directories = .  (single period).